# Trouble determining use of & in this function

Tags: r, function, logical-operators

A friend wrote up this function for determining unique members of a vector.  I can't figure out (mentally) what this one line is doing and it's the crux of the function.  Any help is greatly appreciated

```
myUniq <- function(x){
  len = length(x)                    # getting the length of the argument
  logical = rep(T, len)              # creating a vector of logicals as long as the arg, populating with true
  for(i in 1:len){                   # for i -> length of the argument
    logical = logical & x != x[i]   # logical vector =  logical vector & arg vector where arg vector != x[i] ??????
    logical[i] = T
  }
x[logical]
}
```

This line I can't figure out:

**logical = logical & x != x[i]**

can anyone explain it to me?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`logical` is a vector, I presume a logical one containing `len` values `TRUE`. `x` is a vector of some other data of the same length.

The second part `x != x[i]` is creating a logical vector with `TRUE` where elements of `x` aren't the same as the current value of `x` for this iteration, and `FALSE` otherwise.

As a result, both sides of `&` are now logical vector. `&` is an element-wise AND comparison the result of this is `TRUE` if elements of `logical` and `x != x[i]` are *both* `TRUE` and `FALSE` otherwise. Hence, after the first iteration, `logical` gets changed to a logical vector with `TRUE` for all elements `x` *not* the same as the `i=1`th element of `x`, and `FALSE` if they are the same.

Here is a bit of an example:

```
logical <- rep(TRUE, 10)
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(letters[1:4], 10, replace = TRUE)

> x
 [1] "b" "b" "c" "d" "a" "d" "d" "c" "c" "a"
> logical
 [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
> x != x[1]
 [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
> logical & x != x[1]
 [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

This seems very complex. Do you get the same results as:

```
unique(x)
```

gives you? If I run my `x` above through `myUniq()` and `unique()` I get the same output:

```
> myUniq(x)
[1] "b" "d" "c" "a"
> unique(x)
[1] "b" "c" "d" "a"
```

(well, except for the ordering...)

Comment: you nailed it!!  I understand it perfectly now!!

It is a round about way of doing things, but we were trying to avoid use of the unique function.  I used loops, which I understood, but not his method.

Comment: You'll get the same ordering (and make the function more efficient) if you replace `for(i in 1:len)` with `for(i in 1:len) if(logical[i])`.  Once you're eliminated all the redundant `a`s, you don't need to look at `a`s again.